# Multiple Conditional formatting to highlight a third cell when two cells match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I wanted to highlight a third cell when a first cell matches with a second cell in a list. I used this formula which worked =COUNTIF(V5,$E$5:$E$310) with V5 being the first cell and e5 to e310 being the list I'm looking in. This worked out well except the problem is I have almost 600 cells I want to do this too and I don't want to have to enter in each cell the same conditional formating. When I tried to do it for all cells I realised that I could only get them to look in the same first cell V5, not V5 then the next cell down V6 then V7 etc.
Is there a way to do mass conditional formatting or this or any other type of way to basically highlight or fill in a third cell when matching a 1st with a second cell in a list with the 1st cell changing by dropping down a cell each time?
I hope I've explained this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `=COUNTIF(V5,$E$5:$E$310)` is giving you the results you want? 
I believe that you should be using `=COUNTIF($E$5:$E$310,V5)`.

Are the 600 cells in the same column, consecutive? 
If so, just select them, go into Conditional Formatting, and insert the rule. 
It should work the way you want

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you want. If my answer doesn’t work for you, please edit your question to be clearer about what you are trying to do and what happens.